# process a part of a large CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a `.csv` file and add values for the corresponding month.
For example, if my file has 3 years of data and I want to find the sum of the values that correspond to january in those 3 years.

File example:

```
jan2000,4.5
feb2000,9 
jan2001,9.0 
feb2001,8.9
```

and so on..

I know how to open the file and convert the file into a `list` using `split` and `strip`.

I do not understand how to append specific elements to a list because my data has almost 50 years and its a dumb idea to go for if statements.

Comment: Do you need to start somewhere in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv  # let's let the csv module handle the details of reading a csv file
import collections  # we'll need a defaultdict to track all the data

# open the file we want to read from and the file we want to write to
with open("path/to/input") as infile, open("path/to/output", 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')  # let the csv library handle csv.writer handle the details of writing the actual data to the file
    months = collections.defaultdict(int)  # keep track of the input data
    for month, val in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=','):
        val = float(val)
        month = month[:3]  # we don't need the year
        months[month] += val  # add to the running total
    for month in 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split():  # we need a list of all the months in proper order
        outfile.writerow([month, months[month])  # get the value from the data we've been tracking
```

Answer (score 0):

The `open`, `strip` and `split` functions are acceptable for reading CSV files is arguably it would be more straightforward to use a [module like this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Reading CSV then becomes:

```
import csv
with open('fiftyyears.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        do_something(row)
```

I'm not sure what is dumb about using if statements, but the date format you list as an example is a bit odd. Also, 10 lines of real data would have been more useful to help answer your question.

There are lots of ways to solve your month correlation requirement. A basic approach would be something like:

```
import csv

class MonthCorrelator(object):
    def __init__(self, month):
        self.month = month

    def process(self, row):
        # code goes here to say "if the row's month is my month then..."

    def finish(self):
        # code goes here to print the result

processor = MonthCorrelator('jan2000') # or, better, use datetime

with open('fiftyyears.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        processor.process(row)

processor.finish()
```

...which would work but may be more code than you need.

If all you want to do is

- read data
- filter certain rows
- on those rows do a sum

then look into iterators, [predicates for a filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), and the [built-in sum function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: By dumb i meant i have 50 years of data and there are 12 months in a year adding upto almost 600 if statements considering one for each month of a specific year

Comment: 600 rows ... is trivial. 50Gb of CSV is more interesting, and even then still fine. I think, though, that you mean something more sensible than doing 'if' statements on each of 12 months, which is fair. I thought you were seeking a particular month, but I think you mean correlate all months listed. Either way, iterators and filters will be good for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all the heavy lifting yourself, without taking much help from the standard library:

```
with open("path/to/input") as infile, open("path/to/output", 'w') as outfile:
    months = {}
    for line in infile:
        month, val = line.strip().split(',')
        val = float(val)
        month = month[:3]
        if month not in months:
            months[month] = 0
        months[month] += val
    for month in 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split():
        outfile.write(','.join([month, str(months[month])))
```

Comment: I still do not understand how do i append the corresponding value of the month to a list.
For example, for 3 years jan will have 3 different values. 
Now how to append only those values to a list and exclude other months while iteration.
Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Since you want the totals, you don't need to track the actual values - simply use a running sum for each month, which you can track in a dictionary. So I've created a dictionary called `months` in which the keys are the names of the months, and the values are the total for the corresponding month (key)

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to find the elements you need other than scanning each one for "jan"

Computers are really fast and this is an operation with O(n) complexity (not that complex). I think your answer would look something like this assuming you parse the CSV file into a List of Months and values

```
isJan = False
sum = 0.0
for item in monthList:
    if isJan:
        sum += float(item)
    if "jan" in item:
        isJan = True
    else:
        isJan = False
print sum
```